# why is my GPU temp a negative number?

Tags: gpu, temperature, amd-radeon

when idling, the GPU (AMD Radeon HD 8570D) tends to list numbers around -3C.
when it's running a 100% for a while it get up to 11C. 
is there some sort of math going on to get these numbers or does it just have a bad thermometer?

Comment: How are you reading the temperatures?  If it's software, then are you sure the software being used is compatible with your motherboard's chipset/SMBIOS and GPU?  Also, have you tried more than one piece of monitoring software?  Do others show anything different?

Comment: using Kombuster(MSI); using Afterburner MSI; temp measured in CGMiner; looks like GPU-Z shows the correct temperature though.